# How to model the discrepancy between test result and prediction code, and find the main sources of discrepancy

Tags: model, lasso, ridge-regression

I have data about some tested machines, stored as a database with $\approx$ 300 observations, 40 predictors, 2 outcomes. The two outcomes (responses) are the result of the machine test for that specific observation, and the test result prediction from a physics-based performance prediction code. I would like to understand which predictors, if any, contribute the most to the discrepancy between the code predictions and the test results. The tests have a certain variability: when a group of machines of identical design was tested, $\pm1.5\%$ variation of test results was found.

How should I proceed? My idea is to start simple - use LASSO or ridge regression to build a linear model $\hat{y}(\mathbf{x})$ of the difference between test results and code predictions. Then make residual plots to check if the linear model assumption is tenable: I guess that for LASSO and ridge too, residuals should be normally distributed, independent from $\mathbf{x}$  and homoskedastic. Right? What about assessing whether the assumption of linearity is acceptable? In 1 or 2 dimensions, one can look at the 2D/3D scatterplot  $(\mathbf{x},y)$ to get an idea. In $\approx$ 40 dimensions, I could look at the 40 scatterplots $(x_i,y)$. Clearly I would use CV errors to choose between the linear model and some nonlinear model such as MARS or LOESS, but I would also like to know if there are some graphs which can  be used to get an idea of whether the relationship between $\mathbf{x}$ and $y$ looks reasonably linear or not.

Anyway, if the linear model looks fine, I can then look at the predictor coefficients to find the most important sources of discrepancy between the test results and the code prediction. If I need to use a nonlinear model, I was thinking of using Sobol indices, unless you have better suggestions.

Comment: What type of physical phenomenon are you observing? I think that a quantitative comparison between the numerical and experimental outcome is only meaningful when you are sure about the stability of the numerical prediction wrt discretization size, any symmetry assumptions etc.

Comment: These test don't study a physical phenomenon. They are acceptance tests for wind turbines. Of course there are physical phenomena at work here (fluid dynamics and turbulence), but the concept is very different from a lab test: you make the test to prove to the customer that the machine works. If the difference between tested performance and performance as predicted by the performance prediction code exceeds a set contractual margin, you owe big penalties to the customer. So you definitely must not exceed the margin.